# Operators permitted in ndarray vector operations

Tags: python, numpy

### Question

I want to know the list of the Operators permitted in ndarray vector operations.

### Question Details

Numpy ndarray can do vector operations such as:

```py
arr  = np.array ( [ [ 1, 2, 3], [ 4, 5, 6] ] )
arr2 = np.array ( [ [-1,-2,-3], [-4,-5,-6] ] )
arr * arr2
```

However, for example,  Operator "or" can't use ndarray vector operations such as:

```py
arr  = np.array ( [ [ True, False, True], [ False, True, False] ] )
arr2 = np.array ( [ [True,True,True], [False,False,False] ] )
arr or arr2
```

Result

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[196], line 1
----> 1 arr or arr2

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I expected: Or operation is done by each elements.

```
[ [ True, True, True], [ False, True, False] ]
```

Then, I want to know the list of the Operators permitted in ndarray vector operations.

### What I try

I searched official documents roughly, but I couldn't find what operators are permitted in ndarray vector operations.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/

### Help

Anybody has (official) information about this ?

write above body "What I try"

Comment: `&` and `|` are the element-wise and/or operators.  `or/and` are not operators.  They are more like the python `if/else`.

Comment: It's in the documentation, under [Arithmetic, matrix multiplication, and comparison operations](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-matrix-multiplication-and-comparison-operations)

Comment: The python interpreter converts operators to method calls, for example `a+b` becomes `a.__add__(b)`.  All those methods have `ufunc` equivalents, such as `np.add(a,b)`.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html

Comment: The problem with `and/or` is that they are short circuiting operations.  Thus `True or foobar` returns True even if `foobar` would otherwise return a NameError. `a or b` is the equivalent of `a if bool(a) else b`.

Comment: Something to watch out for `2<x<5` is ok for scalar `x`.  For an array use `(2<x) & (x<5)`.  The () are important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official Docs says permitted numpy vector  operations are:

(+, -, *, /, //, %, divmod(), ** or pow(), <<, >>, &, ^, |, ~) and the comparisons (==, <, >, <=, >=, !=)

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-matrix-multiplication-and-comparison-operations